# Bad_alloc not thrown when I expect it to

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, out-of-memory

Consider this simple program:

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    const std::size_t size = 1<<31;
    int *a = NULL;

    try
    {
        a = new int[size];
    }
    catch (std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cerr << "caught some bad guy" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    if (a == NULL)
    {
        std::cerr << "it's null, can't touch this" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cerr << "looks like 'a' is allocated alright!" << std::endl;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i ++)
        std::cout << a[i] << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

### Commentary

- I try to allocate some ridiculous amount of memory: `(1<<31) * sizeof(int)` == 8GB
- I add safety checks

  - Catching `std::exception`, which should catch `std::bad_alloc` among other exceptions...
  - Check if it's not null (even though for this check to actually make sense, I'd need `a = new (std::nothrow) int[size]` - but regardless of how I allocate memory, it doesn't work)

### Environment

- RAM installed: 2GB
- Operating system: Debian
- Architecture: 32-bit

### Problem

The problem is that the program, instead of early exit, does something like this:

```
rr-@burza:~$ g++ test.cpp -o test && ./test
looks like 'a' is allocated alright!
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
(...many other zeros here...)
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0Segmentation fault
```

The number of zeros printed is exactly 33790, which tells me exactly... nothing.
How can I make my program segfault-proof?

Comment: Is it 32 or 64 bit system?

Comment: I can demonstrate that the size overflows and `operator new` gets a wrong number of bytes to allocate, but I can't (yet) make a connection to the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: What is the result if you replace `const std::size_t size = 1<<31;`  by `const std::size_t size = std::size_t(1)<<31;` ?

Comment: Replacing it to `std::size_t(1)<<31` doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: @DieterLücking If `int` is indeed four bytes, 1<<31 should not overflow. `sizeof(int) * size` may overflow but that happens later and involves only `size_t` values.

Comment: I'm wondering why you'd print out massive amounts of uninitialized memory.  I wouldn't expect that to tell you much.  Perhaps you should print size to see what you end up with.  I was also wondering if it overflowed for some reason, but when I tried the online c++ compiler I see the exception.  What OS?  I saw the output "size: 18446744071562067968
caught some bad guy"  Obviously that number is so massive that no computer I own could ever allocate that much memory (physical or virtual).

Comment: trying to allocate 8gb on 32b os might be UB, try to shift by 28

Comment: @shawn1874, @NoSenseEtAl: The point of this question is to learn how to make it bulletproof under any circumstances, without resorting to stuff like checking programatically how many RAM is available or anything like that. I'm not going to allocate that much RAM. I want to know, however, what are exact circumstances for `new[]` to fail at reporting that there were problems with allocating and how to deal with them. Also... reading unitialized (but allocated!) memory should show rubbish, yes, but not cause a segfault. And size can be determined only by reading due to nature of this problem..

Comment: My guess is that in your configuration `new[]` overflows and you end up allocating 0 bytes. I think it's a bug. See http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=19351

Comment: Note that in Linux when you map new memory for process it initially contains zeros (unlike malloc might reuse memory previously freed memory so can contain garbage).

Comment: @zch Yeah, I figured as much thanks to delman's comment. But then again, *why 33790*? Googling for "33790 segfault" shows interesting results - it looks like this number isn't random at all.

Comment: I don't think it's very significant number. Maybe allocator maps 135168 (33*4096) bytes and you get address with offset 8. 33790 * 4 = 135160

Comment: 33790 is not reliable anyway... you're not flushing your buffer after each memory read, so can't expect to see a number of 0s exactly corresponding to the amount of memory read, though the buffer's probably relatively small - e.g. 4kb.

Comment: Thanks guys, now I know what causes this behavior (internal `new[]` overflow due to `sizeof(int)*2G` > 32 bit) - so now I'm gonna just test if `(size*sizeof(T))/sizeof(T) == size`, or something similar, before critical `new[]` usages. I'd be glad if you posted a full answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in your environment, which causes integer overflow in implementation of `new[]`. In effect, you are allocating 0 bytes. It might be [this bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=19351). C++03 standard is not clear about what should happen, in C++11 `std::bad_array_new_length` should be thrown.

If you need to support this system you can check if there is chance for overflow before allocating, for example:

```
size_t size_t_max = -1;
if (size > size_t_max / sizeof(int))
    throw ...;
```

This bug might still affect you however if libraries you use don't have such checks (for example implementation of `std::vector`).